# How to prove Schwarzian derivative property

Tags: calculus

If $f$ is three times differentiable and $f'(x) ≠ 0$ , the Schwarzian derivative of $f$ at $x$ is defined to be

$Sf(x)=\frac{f^{'''}(x)}{f^{'}(x)}-\frac{3}{2}(\frac{f^{''}(x)}{f^{'}(x)})^2$

I got curious but could not demonstrate the following property:

$S(f∘g)=[Sf ∘g]*(g^{'})^2+Sg$

I am very sorry I can't give what I've done, it is because I have no idea what to do, I would be very glad to get help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It must be:
$$Sf(x)=\frac{f^{'''}(x)}{f^{'}(x)}-\frac{3}{2}\left(\frac{f^{''}(x)}{f^{'}(x)}\right)^\color{red}2.$$
The derivatives:
$$\begin{align}(f(g(x))'&=f'g'\\
(f(g(x))''&=(f'g')'=f''g'^2+f'g''\\
(f(g(x))'''&=(f''g'^2+f'g'')'=f'''g'^3+2f''g'g''+f''g'g''+f'g'''\\
\end{align}$$
The LHS:
$$\begin{align}S(f∘g)&=\frac{f'''g'^3+3f''g'g''+f'g'''}{f'g'}-\frac32\cdot \frac{(f''g'^2+f'g'')^2}{(f'g')^2}=\\
&=\frac{2f'''f'g'^4+6f''f'g'^2g''+2f'^2g'''g'-3f''^2g'^4-6f''f'g''g'^2-3f'^2g''^2}{2f'^2g'^2}=\\
&=\frac{2f'''f'g'^4+2f'^2g'''g'-3f''^2g'^4-3f'^2g''^2}{2f'^2g'^2}.\end{align}$$
The RHS:
$$\begin{align}[Sf∘g]*(g'(x))^2+Sg&=\left(\frac{f^{'''}(g(x))}{f^{'}(g(x))}-\frac{3}{2}\left(\frac{f^{''}(g(x))}{f^{'}(g(x))}\right)^2\right)\cdot g'^2+\frac{g^{'''}(x)}{g^{'}(x)}-\frac{3}{2}\left(\frac{g^{''}(x)}{g^{'}(x)}\right)^2=\\
&=\frac{2f'''f'g'^2-3f''^2g'^2}{2f'^2}+\frac{g'''}{g'}-\frac{3g''^2}{2g'^2}=\\
&=\frac{2f'''f'g'^4-3f''^2g'^4+2f'^2g'''g'-3f'^2g''^2}{2f'^2g'^2}.\end{align}$$